# How to get a specific field from JSON file?

Tags: json, ruby, mongodb

I use JSON from local mongo.

I wanted to get a specific field from the JSON file. I stuck on this point. Could somebody help me with this? Thank you in advance for your help.

```
!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'mongo'
require 'json'

Mongo::Logger.logger.level = ::Logger::FATAL

client = Mongo::Client.new([ '...' ], :database => 'bms')

client[:bookings].find(:ref_ => '...').each do |document|

<-----# I want to get field (reference) from JSON."

end

client.close
```

Comment: are you use node with mongodb ?

Comment: Yes, I use a node with MongoDB.

Comment: Please share input data and output data at jsoneditor online

Comment: I have just this part of JSON file.
ref_provider: "...",
hilt: {
reference: "...",
clientId: "...",
clientType: "...",
clientName: "..."
},
status: "...",
supplier: {
name: "..."
},
date_from_local: "..."

Comment: this data not save in mongo database ?  data share at https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: I was able to make it, added 
client[:bookings].find(:ref_anixe => '5a4i3').flat_map do |document|
document["services"].map {|x| x["hilt"]["reference"]}

Answer (score 0):

JSONPath may help in this case.

https://github.com/joshbuddy/jsonpath

Answer (score 0):

Use projection to retrieve parts of the documents from MongoDB.

https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/current/tutorials/ruby-driver-projections/